# AllenNLP Torch Version Unavailable

Tags: pip, allennlp

I am trying to install allennlp via pip on the latest version of macOS Catalina. The Python version is 3.9.0. The pip version is 20.2.4.

I was just able to install only a couple of weeks ago, but now I receive the following error when I run the command:

`pip3 install allennlp allennlp-models`

```
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch<1.8.0,>=1.6.0 (from allennlp)
```

This is really bad because a time-sensitive project I am working on right now completely depends on allennlp working. I needed to reinstall due to some git issues, and my virtual env was reset. What can I do to resolve this issue?

Thanks.

EDIT: Somehow I ended up uninstalling 3.9 in homebrew and now I'm stuck at jsonnet. It errors out. I saw some posts about this issue, but none of the recommendations work.

EDIT2: I tried reinstalling brew's python 3.9. jsonnet standalone works again, but then I have the pytorch issue again.

I'm stuck in a loop. Neither the system macOS 3.8 python nor the latest 3.9 home-brew python works. I'd rather get the home-brew python working, but there's no valid version of torch available for that one apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do NOT accidentally use home-brew to download the latest Python 3.9. That isn't compatible with a lot of the required libraries.

Phew.

Comment: We generally recommend conda for all things Python.